# Python: AttributeError: can't set attribute. No puedo crear mi instancia

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un error al crear mi instancia

```
#! python3

class Profile(object):
    """contiene la informacion del perfil"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None    

    @property
    def name(self):
        """name"""
        return self.name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile1 = Profile()
```

El error que me tira:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Project\profile.py", line 14, in <module>
  profile1 = Profile()
File "F:\Project\profile.py", line 6, in __init__
  self.name = None  
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Le estuve dando vuelta un rato, pero no le encuentro sentido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es causado porque tu atributo `self.name` esta chocando con la propiedad `name`, y al hacerlo quiere usar el setter de la propiedad. Lo común es establecer el nombre del atributo con: `_`, por ejemplo en tu caso cambia `self.name` con `self._name`.

```
class Profile(object):
    """contiene la informacion del perfil"""
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None    

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile1 = Profile()
```

O implementa el setter:

```
class Profile(object):
    """contiene la informacion del perfil"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None    

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile1 = Profile()
```